# SUBSTRING / CHARINDEX ADVICE

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following field in my database:

```
|     FileName     |
+------------------+ 
| 4_20191118113041 |
```

**What I am trying to achieve is just return the 4**, so anything before the underscore _. That 4 though could be 100 or 1000 or 1000000 and so on - but I need to always return anything before the _.

I'm guessing it's a combination of SUBSTRING / CHARINDEX but I can't get it to do what I need - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

```
substring(FileName, 1, charindex('_', FileName) - 1)
```